# How do you save a UserControl xaml to an XML File and not get all the un-necessary details?

Tags: c#, xaml

I am trying to save the following UserControl to a file:

```
<local:MyUserControl Name="uc1" ></local:MyUserControl>
```

I am using the following code to save out the user control to a file:

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream("File.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
System.Windows.Makrup.XamlWriter.Save(uc1, fs);
```

This works except that the output isn't just the line up above.  It lists all the XAML in my user control (labels, textbox, combo box, etc.).

When I save multiple user control instances to a .xaml file and then try and read that XAML file back in, the XamlReader takes issue with the same Name being used.

Thank you!

Comment: Very good point.  One of the issues I am running into is that I am trying to export multiple user controls into a file (which works).  The problem arises when I try and bring them back in and it gives me an error that I can't have my labels named the same name (lbldescription).  I can't find a way around this so I thought another way might be better to go with.

Comment: These names are defined inside the UserControl.xaml.  I don't think I can change them can I?

Comment: I just made an update to this question.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Why are you doing this? What are you trying to achieve by saving individual controls to XML files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on this post:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/cdf0cf6c-3f8e-42cf-a81e-008f3af3b95c/

I have discovered that naming controls inside a User Control is not allowed.  A custom control seems to be the better way to go.

Comment: Exactly right about the names!  I ended up using Dependency Properties to avoid using names.